# static reference for bitmap in the ondraw method

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am have a `SurfaceView` where I like to draw a bunch of text and draw a png image 72px by 72px. The image is always drawn on the `SurfaceView` but in different location every 2 second.

Is it bad idea to create a static reference to the bitmap (from that image) and use it every time? I am trying to avoid the overhead of "initialising" the bitmap since it is the same image all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with static references in memory management is that you will need to collect the garbage yourself. i.e., you will need to **recycle the bitmap** and make it null as soon as it is no longer in use.

Since you are using it in multiple places, it should be okay as long as you are careful about it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a static reference, it would be better, I think, to use an instance reference in the `SurfaceView` and initialize it in the view's `onCreate()` method. That way, initialization isn't an issue (you automatically have a context you can use to load the image). Also, the bitmap automatically goes away when the view itself is garbage collected.

If you're creating a new `SurfaceView` every two seconds, that's a different story. A static reference might make sense in that scenario. But then I'd wonder about your app design. :)

Comment: I tried to simplify the question but maybe I confused you more. What's happening is that I have a surface view that covers the whole screen. Then I have many Views created. Each view is drawn at a random location every second. All these views are of the same object type so all of them display the same image but at different location. Inside the ondraw of the view, is where the bitmap is drawn. I am wondering if it would be OK to have a static reference to bitmap that is used by all these views

Comment: @Snake - So those views are overlays to the surface view? When one of them is shown, does the previous one go away? Do they need to be views or could they be a display list drawn directly by the surface view?

Comment: these views are overlays on the surface view (think of it camera surface view with AR views on top). In average I have around 10 views drawn every second (sort of like s refresh screen ) where all the views are cleared and 10 are drawn randomly